# How do I pass a variable from a function to a WTForm? I use the variable to choose RadioField choices

Tags: python-2.7, flask-wtforms

I am trying to pass a session variable into a WTForm.  I use the variable to choose the RadioField entry.

I have tried to pass it as a regular variable, but the WTForm doesn't recognize the variable. I have tried different arguments, but it still does not recognize it inside WTForms.  It is the variable level that I am passing.  I know it all works if I write level = 1 (or 2 or 3) on the first line of the class ZWOForm(Form):  What am I missing?

From **init.py** :

```
class ZWOForm(Form):
    zwotitle = TextField('Title', [validators.Length(min=3, max=50)])
    zwotags = TextField('Tags', [validators.Length(min=3, max=50)])
    category = TextField('Category (Your Choice)', [validators.Length(min=3, max=50)])
    if level <3:
        if level <2:
            zwolevel = RadioField('Viewing Level', choices=[('1','Public')], default=1)
        else:
            zwolevel = RadioField('Viewing Level', choices=[('1','Public'),('2','Private')], default=1)
    else:
        zwolevel = RadioField('Viewing Level', choices=[('1','Public'),('2','Private'),('3','Team')], default=1)
        zwodescription = TextAreaField('Description', [validators.Length(min=3, max=200)])      


@app.route('/createzwo/', methods=["GET","POST"])
@login_required
def create_zwo():
    try:
        level = session['level']
        form = ZWOForm(request.form)
        if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():
...
        return render_template("createzwo.html", form=form)
```

From HTML Form:

```
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
<form method=post action="/createzwo/">
    <dl>
        {{render_field(form.zwotitle)}}
        {{render_field(form.zwotags)}}
        {{render_field(form.category)}}
        {{render_field(form.zwolevel)}}
        {{render_field(form.zwodescription)}}
    </dl>
    <p><input type=submit value="Create ZWO File"></p>
</form>
```

From _formhelpers.html:

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
    <dt>{{ field.label }}
    <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
        {% if field.errors %}
            <ul class=errors>
            {% for error in field.errors %}
                <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </dd>
{% endmacro %}
```

Error that I have seen are "level" is not defined and rendering errors that spit our a bunch of lines pointing to other .py files (local and global).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code within the class definition of your form is only ever executed once when the module is initially loaded and at that point the local variable `level` does not exist. Even if it did exist at that point, you would only be setting the class definition once whereas you want the ability to alter the form choices every time it is displayed. This can easily be achieved in your view function. Don't set the field choices in the form class but set them on the form itself after it has been created by setting the value of the field choices attribute. Given that that the number of choices available for each level happens to equal the value of that level, you can use list slicing to generate this list.

```
class ZWOForm(Form):
    zwotitle = TextField('Title', [validators.Length(min=3, max=50)])
    zwotags = TextField('Tags', [validators.Length(min=3, max=50)])
    category = TextField('Category (Your Choice)', [validators.Length(min=3, max=50)])
    zwolevel = RadioField('Viewing Level', choices=[], default=1)
    zwodescription = TextAreaField('Description', [validators.Length(min=3, max=200)])      

@app.route('/createzwo/', methods=["GET","POST"])
@login_required
def create_zwo():        
    try:
        form = ZWOForm(request.form)
        all_choices = [('1','Public'),('2','Private'),('3','Team')]
        choices = all_choices[:session["level"]]
        form.zwolevel.choices = choices

        if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():
            ...
        return render_template("createzwo.html", form=form)
```

Comment: Sorry, the zwodescriotion is on each version, just below the zwo level choices.  This is just the top part of a much longer form.  I will have to absorb the dynamic version you presented as I don't "see" it naturally. That may be a better option.  I will have to play with it more and let you know.

Comment: Given that you just want to alter the radiofield choices and not add/remove fields, I've edited my answer to reflect this. It should hopefully be more straightforward now and easier to understand.

Comment: Yes, I can see what you are doing with the code.  However I get the following error when I apply it:  slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method.  "level" is an integer, but there may be an issue with all_choices or choices throwing an error?

Comment: It sounds like you are storing the level as a string rather than as an integer within the session. Try `choices = all_choices[:int(session["level"])]`.

Comment: I found out that session variables don't actually have any attributes.  So, I forced it as an integer and everything worked!  Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: One more item:  How can I have the radiofields show inline?  I have tried wrapping them in the html template itself, but that doesn't work.  I have also looked for some additional options to add to the render_field, but can't find any for the radiofields.